# How to properly use the CI-Merchant library's config file

Tags: codeigniter, codeigniter-2, ci-merchant

I am trying to add items to `merchant.php` (the [**CI-Merchant**](http://ci-merchant.org/) library's config file, which I believe is auto-loaded by CodeIgniter). I want to be able to set the settings for the payment gateway (driver) I am choosing in the settings so that I don't have to write it out in every controller that is calling the library/driver and I do not want to hardcode the settings in the driver.

These are the settings I am trying to save, but I could have others with different gateways:

```php
$config['authorize_net']['api_login_id'] = '***';
$config['authorize_net']['transaction_key'] = '***';
$config['authorize_net']['test_mode'] = TRUE;
$config['authorize_net']['developer_mode'] = TRUE;
```

However this is causing 2 warnings. The first:

```
A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: Warning
Message: stripos() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given
Filename: libraries/merchant.php
Line Number: 97
```

And the second:

```
A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: Warning
Message: strtolower() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given
Filename: libraries/merchant.php
Line Number: 103
```

So it seems to me that CodeIgniter is automatically passing the `merchant.php` config file to the library but it was not expecting it (which also confuses me, because in the CI-Merchant download it comes with the config file).

My worst case scenario would be to change the "default settings" in `merchant_authorize_net.php` the  but I really want to avoid this, below is what that default settings function looks like.

```php
public function default_settings()
{
    return array(
        'api_login_id' => '',
        'transaction_key' => '',
        'test_mode' => FALSE,
        'developer_mode' => FALSE,
    );
}
```

My questions are:

- Is there a proper way to use the CI-Merchant's config file?
- If not, is there a way to have driver-specific config files in CodeIgniter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The config file is actually just there as boilerplate code which should probably be removed. CI-merchant itself doesn't have any logic to automatically read the config file for you.

Generally the recommended approach is to store the settings in your own config file (or environment variables), and then use those settings in your controller to initialize the library. You are correct that it's best to try and avoid editing anything inside the library folder.

If you are starting a new project I also recommend you check out [Omnipay](https://github.com/adrianmacneil/omnipay), the successor to CI-Merchant, as CI-Merchant will not be receiving any further development.

Comment: Thanks Adrian. I ended up just using the Authorize.net CIM library instead. I saw Omnipay before and like it but I didn't know how well it integrated with CodeIgniter since there was no info about it. I see you are a contributor of Omnipay, are you planning to make a library for CI for those of us who aren't familiar with Composer.

Comment: I'm the author of both libraries :) It's really simple to use composer with codeigniter, I'd recommend just using that rather than writing any CI-specific code. Composer will make your life a lot better :)

Comment: I'll check it out on my next project. Thanks!